# Rewrite rule conflict in htaccess file?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have write rule in my htaccess file but two rules conflict each other.
My htaccess file is :

```
# BEGIN REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES
RewriteRule ^service-status/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^country/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^company/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
# END REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/numero/$ ?country=$1
RewriteRule ^introduction/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) ?company=$1
RewriteRule ^pays/(.+)?$ /pays?company=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?country=$1&company=$2

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /ade/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /ade/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
all rule working fine but 
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?country=$1&company=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/numero/$ ?country=$1
conflict each other both are working fine Individually
```

I want url like 
1. http://abc.com/country-name/companyname/

```
(RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?country=$1&company=$2)
```

2.http://abc.com/country-name/numero/ (numero is fix key word)

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/numero/$ ?country=$1
```

I will appreciate your help.
Thanks 
Ballu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
# BEGIN REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES
RewriteRule ^service-status/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^country/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^company/(.+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
# END REMOVE SLUG CUSTOM POST TYPE RULES


RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/numero/$ ?country=$1
RewriteRule ^introduction/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+) ?company=$1
RewriteRule ^pays/(.+)?$ /pays?company=$1
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?country=$1&company=$2

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /ade/
 RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /ade/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/numero/$ ?country=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /index.php?country=$1&company=$2 [L]
```